# Suggestion for using web framework for mobile app & desktop

Tags: android, ios, django, jquery-mobile, playframework-2.2

I am involved in developing application for mobile sensors, data from these sensors is to be collected using Android/iOS mobile apps. We want the end users to be able to view this data from desktops also. This data is uploaded to be uploaded to our own database(s) from the mobile apps. I have done this development of the prototypes using native applications (iOS/Android) and implemented web services using Django 1.6 with SQL database. This was just for prototype.

We are at stage where we really need to make this into real product with paying customers, so we are in position to revisit our technology stack question. So I am looking for suggestions.

Currently I am thinking of using Play Framework on the server side. I really haven't seen anything compelling that can provide Native app like feel so we will have to keep developing mobile apps using native libraries. We will interface with our web services using REST API. My concern with Play framework is it doesn't seem to have lot of plugins similar to django, but its early days hoping that situation will improve.

Is this right approach we are very small team ( 4 people, we can hire 2 more probably). Given this is this right technology path I am choosing anything I should be looking at?

I have looked at Parse library but doesn't seem to offer too much data flexibility, geared towards more social media aspects.

We will be using StromPath for user management, any other choices I should be looking at for user management?

We really don't want to do a lot of MVC programming on client side, so on desktop app we will keep it simple jQuery/Javascript & html

-Sam

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery mobile you can assure the look and feel like in a native app. The library it self does media queries and stretch or shrink the content accordingly. So in terms of UI you will not face any problem providing native app like look and feel to the users. For client/server communication I recommend normal ajax functionality so you can dynamically add content.

When working with JQM there are certain rules that you will have to obey.